# Service onDestroy() gets called immediately

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am trying to keep my Service running in the foreground for as long as a user is logged in. I used the code on the Android Developer [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) plus some of my own.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("KeepAliveService onCreate");
    phoneState = PhoneState.getInstance();

    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNM.cancel(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID); // in case of crash the icon is not removed

    Intent notifIntent = new Intent(this, incomingReceivedActivity);
    notifIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notifIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    mNotifContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mNotif = createNotification(this, mNotifContentIntent);

    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    startWifiLock();

    instance = this;

    // Retrieve methods to publish notification and keep Android
    // from killing us and keep the audio quality high.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        try {
            mSetForeground = getClass().getMethod("setForeground", mSetFgSign);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Couldn't find foreground method", e);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            mStartForeground = getClass().getMethod("startForeground", mStartFgSign);
            mStopForeground = getClass().getMethod("stopForeground", mStopFgSign);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Couldn't find startGoreground or stopForeground", e);
        }
    }

    startForegroundCompat(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotif);

    if (!mTestDelayElapsed) {
        // Only used when testing. Simulates a 5 seconds delay for launching service
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                mTestDelayElapsed = true;
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    //make sure the application will at least wakes up every 5 mn
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, KeepAliveHandler.class);
    mkeepAlivePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
                                                                                        , SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+300000
                                                                                        , 300000
                                                                                        , mkeepAlivePendingIntent);
}
```

With this block of code the onDestory gets called immediately. I need to be able to keep the Service running the whole time. I added print outs to see where the issue may happen but so far I can't figure it out.

LogCat:

```
05-27 17:35:20.777: I/System.out(20600): KeepAliveService onCreate
05-27 17:35:20.785: V/KeepAliveService(20600): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!startForegroundCompat!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
05-27 17:35:20.785: V/KeepAliveService(20600): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!invokeMethod!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
05-27 17:35:20.785: V/KeepAliveService(20600): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!notifyWrapper!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
05-27 17:35:20.871: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 552K, 6% free 11353K/11952K, paused 12ms, total 13ms
05-27 17:35:21.066: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 316K, 3% free 11872K/12224K, paused 17ms, total 20ms
05-27 17:35:21.207: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 412K, 4% free 12430K/12896K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
05-27 17:35:21.332: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 698K, 6% free 12925K/13660K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
05-27 17:35:21.543: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 783K, 6% free 13501K/14320K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
05-27 17:35:21.605: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 6% free 13517K/14320K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
05-27 17:35:21.605: I/dalvikvm-heap(20600): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.161MB for 972816-byte allocation
05-27 17:35:21.636: D/dalvikvm(20600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 14466K/15272K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
05-27 17:35:22.191: I/System.out(20600): KeepAliveService onDestroy
05-27 17:35:22.191: V/KeepAliveService(20600): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!stopForegroundCompat!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
05-27 17:35:22.191: V/KeepAliveService(20600): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!invokeMethod!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

How can I make the Service (It is a Service not a IntentService) last until I call `stopService`?

I have looked at the following stack overflow questions and nothing has helped me thus far

[Service.onDestroy() is called directly after creation, anyway the Service does its work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570885/service-ondestroy-is-called-directly-after-creation-anyway-the-service-does-i)

[Android service killed immediately after start, despite calling startForeground()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040460/android-service-killed-immediately-after-start-despite-calling-startforeground)

Answer (score 1):

All I did was removed my stopService on my Login onDestroy callback

Before

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Login onDestroy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    stopService(new Intent(ACTION_MAIN).setClass(this, KeepAliveService.class));
}
```

After

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}
```